# Error when trying to connect on redis memory database (StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I don't know why but when I ended the section of this feature it was working but now it does not work anymore

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kjnO.png)

I'm using Redis, to be precise this version 2.6.86 and ASP.NET Core 8.

This is how I'm injecting my service in my services collection

```
// Adding our connection to Redis (it must be Singleton because it will share shared by all users)
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(opt =>
{
    string redisConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("Redis");
    var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(redisConnectionString);
 
    // It's in this line that the error occurs
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
});
```

And this is my appsettings.json

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Data source=skinet.db",
   "IdentityConnection": "Data source=identity.db",
   "Redis": "localhost"
 },
```

If it's useful this is my service, not so useful because it's not even reaching the controller endpoint

```
 public class BasketRepository : IBasketRepository
 {
     private readonly IDatabase _database;

     public BasketRepository(IConnectionMultiplexer redis)
     {
         _database = redis.GetDatabase();
     }

     public async Task<bool> DeleteBasketAsync(string basketId)
     {
         return await _database.KeyDeleteAsync(basketId);
     }

     public async Task<CustomerBasket?> GetBasketAsync(string basketId)
     {
         var data = await _database.StringGetAsync(basketId);

         return data.IsNullOrEmpty ? null : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CustomerBasket>(data!);
     }

     public async Task<CustomerBasket?> UpsertBasketAsync(CustomerBasket basket)
     {
         // If exists in memory it will replace else it will create
         var created = await _database.StringSetAsync(basket.Id, JsonSerializer.Serialize(basket), TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

         if (!created) 
             return null;

         return await GetBasketAsync(basket.Id);
     }
 }
```

If you want to see the complete code it's on my github: https://github.com/GuilhermeMarques457/Skinet

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages. Instead post the actual test in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your Redis connection string is wrong. You have to define the port as well. Default port is 6379. So `"Redis": "localhost:6379"`.

> A typical connection string is of the form:
> `HOST_NAME:PORT_NUMBER,password=PASSWORD` where `HOST_NAME` is the host
> name of your server (e.g. `localhost`), `PORT_NUMBER` is the port number
> Redis is listening on (e.g. `6379`) and `PASSWORD` is your redis server's
> password (e.g. `secret_password`).

Check https://developer.redis.com/develop/dotnet/.